# Are there TLC stains for organo fluor compounds or anorg. fluoride that are useful for selecting the product containing fractions post purification

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, analytical-chemistry

Are there TLC stains that work with fluoride or with organofluor compounds? I have a fluorinated phosphonic acid that does not stain with conventional means. I did research in many of the known and available staining resources, but I did not find something reliable yet. KMnO4, Phosphomolybdic Acid (PMA) Stain and Cerium Molybdate Stain, p-anisaldehyde as well as Vanilla stain did appear not to work. Do you have experiences here? For me I was not able to see an unambiguously contrast to the background. Maybe there is also a protocol that decomposes an organofluor compound beforehand and makes fluoride visible on TLC? I performed  many tests but nothing was really convincing until now. I know that a protocol for qualitative prove of F- uses chromic acid and the discoloration of alizarin dye - but this system is probably not applicable for TLCs.

Comment: What about TLC plates/sheets with UV254nm fluorescent indicator?

Comment:  The product is UV inactive. When it would be UV active I would not try all these stains.

Comment: You do not provide relevant product properties to prevent not applicable suggestions in your questions. I have warned you what that leads to.

Comment: It seems that unfortunately it is not possible to stain fluoride containing compounds (C-F) bonds present in the compound.